# Dynamically Link to PDF

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, hyperlink

I am trying to make a link to a pdf that is located within my file system via a recordset.  The file name is inside a column called 'file'.

Cant figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="compTime" class="equipmenttroublereportSubmit" id="compTime">
<table cellpadding="4">
<tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>uploaddate</td>
  <td>schedulemonth</td>
  <td>version</td>
  <td>comments</td>
  <td>file</td>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['uploaddate']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['schedulemonth']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['version']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['comments']; ?></td>
  <td>echo '<a href="/_NewSite/Schedules' . $row_recordsetName['file'] . '">' . $row_recordsetName['file'] .'</a>';</td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
 <p class="compTimeForm">&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `do while` in this case, you must use `while`, since the value applied in the while will be used in the first loop

Comment: can you post the link that is generated by this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing some code there?

```
<td>**<?php** echo '<a href="/_NewSite/Schedules' . $row_recordsetName['file'] . '">' . $row_recordsetName['file'] .'</a>';</td>
```

Comment: I noticed this after I sent the post.  Still not working though :(

Comment: No problem. When things don't work out the way you want, always think how can you dig in to understand where is the problem coming from. This way you can debug your actions and recover from errors ;]

Comment: Exactly. I saw that in the browser it was pointing to the directory.  Forgot a slash before the file name.  Thanks again!